# IntelliJ looking for appcfg.sh, but only appcfg.py exists

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating an AppEngine webapp and would like to be able to deploy it from IntelliJ.  However, the plugin fails to deploy because it's looking for appcfg.sh in the AppEngine SDK directory.  That directory contains an appcfg.py file, but no .sh file.  Is the plugin just out of date?  Is there a work around?

Google Cloud SDK 249.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.74

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appcfg.sh` was (or maybe still is) available in the GAE-only Java SDK, but not in the gcloud SDK (click on `Download and install the original App Engine SDK for Java.` at the bottom of the [Download Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download) page).

The JetBrains tools are a bit behind in this regard  (same applied to the last PyCharm Pro version I used - it supported the GAE Python SDK, not the gcloud one). Which is why I have both SDKs installed, using them alternatively as needed.

Notes:

- at least in the PyCharm case only the Pro version had GAE support, the Community Edition didn't
- the GAE SDKs are no longer actively kept at par with the gcloud SDK, some newer GAE features aren't available through them, so YMMV.